# Threading error while deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, multithreading, json.net, async-await, httpclient

So I made a request wrapper for my clients, and everything was working fine. But suddenly (I have no clue why) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(c)` throws the classic exception

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Well I don't see any other thread but this one. All of them are local variables and according to Newtonsoft https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/469

> A new JsonSerializerInternalReader is created each time you deserialize an object

Do you have any clue where is the another thread this exception is talking about?

```
    public static Task<Response<T>> _reqWrapper<T>(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> request) 
        where T : class
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var response = new Response<T>();

            var hrm = await request().ConfigureAwait(false);                              
            var c = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(c);

            return response;
        });
```

Already tried this without luck.

```
response.Content = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(c));
```

**Update**

To be sure that that line is the one throwing I made this:

```
T t = null;
try
{
    t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(c);
}
catch { }
response.Content = t
```

And everything is running fine. Any clues?

**Update 2**

Stack trace

What I see here is that the serializer is trying to access the main window. I have to say that this is happening inside a `ShowDialog()` window, so I guess the main window is not available. But I'm not sure if I am correct or how to fix this.

> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
>      at System.Windows.Application.get_MainWindow()
>      at ControliWindows.Globals.Controli.get_Window() in C:...
>      at ControliWindows.Globals.Framework.Modalizer.SaveableModel1..ctor() in C:...
>      at ControliWindows.Views.Modals.AccountMm..ctor() in C:...
>      at CreateControliWindows.Views.Modals.AccountMm()
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
>      at ControliWindows.Globals.Connection.<>c__DisplayClass39_0`1.<<_reqWrapper>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:...

Comment: Once you await something, you may well be running on a different thread once you resume.  Not sure why that matters though in this case.

Comment: Are you sure this is the part that's throwing the exception? I have never seen this exception occurring for anything other than updating UI components on a desktop app. What is `request` doing?

Comment: Try it without the `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @Rob Request is and HttpClient function the case where it throws is `Client.PostAsync(uri, content)` where `Client = new HttpClient()`

Comment: @bto.rdz That's an entirely different piece of code to what you posted.. :)

Comment: @Rob I wish that but I am sure it is happening there

Comment: @bto.rdz Please post your entire code, because it's almost definitely not related to your snippet above. Somewhere, there will be a piece of code interacting with a UI component. At the very least, the exception is happening on your `PostAsync`, which means your response code which you've posted hasn't even executed yet.

Comment: @EricJ. normally code after `await` will run on original thread for WinForms/WPF/ASP.Net... Indeed it is not the case in OP's code as they explicitly request not to come back to original thread (twice) - once with `Task.Run` and just to be absolutely sure with `ConfigureAwait(false)`...

Comment: @Rob Now I am completely sure, please see update any ideas are apreciated

Comment: What's `Response<T>`? Does it interact with UI somehow? If yes, it's possible it's owned by a different thread because you instantiate it at the beginning of the method. Try moving the instantiation after the await to make sure `Content` property is set on the same thread.

Comment: @Groo `Response<T>` is a new object, the point of this wrapper is to return a new object of `Response<T>` it is not in the UI because I am asking for it to this method. I think it is a bug with newtonsoft I am cloning the repo and trying to debug it and see where the error is

Comment: I understand you are instantiating it in this method, but my question was if it captures current synchronization context in its constructor, or something like that (and then the thread changes before you try setting its `Current` property). But looking at the try/catch example, it seems the exception really happens in the serializer. Perhaps there are some static event handlers attached to the serializer which trigger some UI stuff? Anyway, since you're able to checkout newtonsoft's source code, I am sure you'll find the cause when you step through.

Comment: I reckon take the Task.Run, etc out of the picture here - just await things and don't use ConfigureAwait(false).  You won't be switching to other logical call contexts then and perhaps it'll all just be fine.  If you do then need to spin up a separate thread, and thus have things run genuinely in parallel (rather than allowing overlapping response via async/await), introduce it gently and see what causes your failure to return.

Comment: @bto.rdz: If it is in fact the deserialization that is throwing the exception, then you should be able to capture the JSON that is causing it and remove the `HttpClient` stuff entirely from your example code.

Comment: Post the full exception. There is no need to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess() at System.Windows.Application.get_MainWindow() at ControliWindows.Globals.Controli.get_Window() in C:... at ControliWindows.Globals.Framework.Modalizer.SaveableModel1..ctor() in C:... at ControliWindows.Views.Modals.AccountMm..ctor() in C:... at

That is the source of your problem. Here is the series of events that is happening:

- Your `T` is a  `ControliWindows.Views.Modals.AccountMm` and `DeserializeObject` must make a new one of them
- `AccountMm`'s constructor it is creating a `ControliWindows.Globals.Framework.Modalizer.SaveableModel1`
- `SaveableModel1`'s constructor it is reading the property `ControliWindows.Globals.Controli.Window`
- in `Controli.Window` it is reading the property `System.Windows.Application.Window`
- `Application.Window` can only be read from the UI thread, this whole chain of events happens on a Threadpool thread and causes your exception.

The easiest solution is have `ControliWindows.Globals.Controli.Window` detect if it is not on the UI thread and if it is not invoke to the UI to get the value of `Application.Window`.

```
public static class Controli
{
    public Window Window
    {
        get
        {
            var application = Application.Current;
            if(application == null)
                return null;
            try
            {
                return application.MainWindow;
            }
            catch(InvalidOperationException)
            {
                return application.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => application.MainWindow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am amazed that you described my code just with the stack trace I wish I could read all that. what you say makes a lot of sense I will try it. Thanks

Comment: @bto.rdz I updated with a example of how to invoke if nessessary, this code was written in the website so there may be a error or two.

Comment: @bto.rdz see how easy it is to diagnose such problems when looking at the full exception information?

Comment: @usr Thanks for that tip, I guess I need practice reading stack traces. That did not mean too much for me, but there is everything

Comment: @bto.rdz in the future use the [Copy Exception Details to Clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) link in the debugger then just paste the text inside `<pre></pre>` tags in your question (The tags help keep the formatting of the text). That gives you the exception name, the message, and the stack trace all in a single click (it is coping the output of `.ToString()` of your exception, when you want to log a exception use `.ToString()` to get the same message in your code)

Answer (score 0):

By using `ConfigureAwait(false)` you are explicitly telling your await to not try to resume the execution of the code on the same thread after performing your await.

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx):

> continueOnCapturedContext
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> **true** to attempt to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured; otherwise, **false**.

Try using `ConfigureAwait(true)` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, just don't call `ConfigureAwait` at all - the default behaviour is it to mimic `ConfigureAwait(true)`.

Comment: that is quite surprising, then. can you make sure you really are not on the same thread ? With the Thread debug tools you can get their ID or even name them. If it doesn't work, you could try, ContinueWith using FromCurrentSynchronizationContext, instead of awaiting the task, but I thought awaits were already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Deserilization happens in another thread. It opens own thread